# Add background images to div (Dynamic content)

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV ...

```
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Now...In the design and if you think of it as a rectangle has the top as a header and also the footer is different so I cannot just create a 1px background image and repeat it.

I would have to do something like:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="header">This will have a fixed bg image</div>
<div id="body-content">This will have a repeated bg image and it's the part that can grow.</div>
<div id="footer-content">THis will content a fixed bg image for the footer</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone advise on the best way to handle this kind of design CSS wise please?

Comment: Don't use  1px background image, use  >=4px background image instead for better browser performance.

Comment: are the header and footer fixed sizes (height) ?

Comment: Yes, fixed sized height and widths. The only thing that will expand is the middle area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#header
{
   background-image: url('header.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#body
{
   background-image: url('body.png');
   background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

#footer
{
   background-image: url('footer.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Also, you will need to set the `height` and `width` of the `#header` and `footer` `divs`, as the background images will not be used to calculate the `div` size.  If not explicitly set, the images may not show properly.

Comment: And, ensure that the `background-image: url('XXXX.png');` uses a path relative to the .css file.  In the above, images would need to be in the same folder.