# Expandable content div and background functionality

Tags: jquery, background-image, footer, sticky-footer, expandable

I'm new to web design/developing, and have a few questions.

Firstly, I'm interested in finding a method of making content within a page expandable, but not sure how it would affect the image that is set as the background, as well as the rest of the content (navigation, various other divs outside of the div that I want to make expandable). I've been reading up on a couple jQuery scripts for expandable divs and have also studied the "sticky footer", but am still slightly confused on the total process and procedure. I do design for some companies around my town and use various backgrounds that I've made in Photoshop, a lot of them just being basic gradient-style backgrounds.

Anyway, just looking for some answers/suggestions from a web veteran to a beginner.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: BTW, I recommend using CSS to define simple gradients whenever possible rather than using images.  It's more maintainable plus less resources to fetch.  http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Comment: Would you mind making a simple example on jsFiddle.com?  For example, http://jsfiddle.net/quant/44FLk/

Comment: Is this similar to what you want to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094952/add-background-images-to-div-dynamic-content  OK, I'm done commenting now -- sorry for spammy-ness

Comment: Thank you, iX3, I was unaware of the CSS gradient attribute.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you want to achieve or what you have tried so far? What do you mean by "expandable" exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm shooting in the dark here so be nice. Would it work for you to create `DIV` elements and then changing their class from `hidden`to `showable` or something like that?

And you're totally right to be looking at jQuery. At first I thought it was weird but now I love it.

Comment: I could definitely use the method that you suggested, but I found it easy to incorporate the sticky footer, as well as the CSS gradient code the iX3 mentioned above. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: If you like the answer, mark it up and check as an answer. If you find something missing complete it (or tell us what you're unhappy with so we can do that for you). That's how SO works.   :)